# how do I make the sound in my script play only once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I have a script that causes a sound to play when the player gets near the gameObject with the script attached to it. however, the script that plays the sound is being called over
and over as long as the player is within that range, so the sound is playing over and over and over and it sounds all bejumbled together. can you tell me how I could make my script wait for the sound to be done before playing it again? (don`t pay attention to the is player alive bool, that is for something else)

this is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playSiren : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip siren;
    public Transform player;
    public float playerDistance;
    public static bool isPlayerAlive = true;
    private AudioSource source;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isPlayerAlive)
        {
            playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position);

            if (playerDistance < 12f)
            {
                chase();
            }
        }

        void chase()
        {
          source.PlayOneShot(siren);       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to determine if the `chase` method needs to be called or not. For example:

```
    private bool isWithinDistance = false;
    void Update ( )
    {
        if ( isPlayerAlive )
        {
            playerDistance = Vector3.Distance ( player.position, transform.position );
            if ( !isWithinDistance && playerDistance < 12f )
            {
                isWithinDistance = true;
                chase ( );
            }

            if ( isWithinDistance && playerDistance > 12f ) isWithinDistance = false;
        }

        void chase ( )
        {
            source.PlayOneShot ( siren );
        }
    }
```

Note that you're `chase` method is contained within the `Update` method. This is legal in the newer versions of C#, but this may not have been your intended code format? Sub methods like this can only be called from the containing method - which in this case is fine - but you won't be able to call `chase` from anywhere else.

Comment: @Tuckerkunkle the "bool" thing that Tomasz suggested is using the physics engine to replicate the code you literally have already. What exactly is it you're trying to achieve? Do you want the sound to "loop"? What do you mean when you say you want the sound to "come back on"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using distance : use collider , make it a trigger( checkbox in editor)
and then use build in fuctions " onTrigger*something*" to either play sound on enter or wheneveer you want.
Alternative is to add a bool to tell if sound started being played.
Ad another condition that function will not start playing unless boll is false.
Add in update small if statement that if this bool is true it countdowns for like 1 second and makes it false again.